# UIView autolayout crash on IOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Currently I got a problem with autolayout on IOS 6. I don't use autolayout with my view then app crash on IOS 6 ( IOS 7 works fine). If I turn it on the app works fine.

Now I don't want to use autolayout in my view. The issue is about CA layers ( CA layer collect_layers .... blah blah ), I don't know what it is ?

Please help me figure out this. Very thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Editor -> Resolve Auto-Layout Issues -> Clear all constraints in view controller**

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I didn't add any contrainst to the view.

Comment: The error here http://i1162.photobucket.com/albums/q540/trungbq06/ScreenShot2013-10-28at32609PM_zpsdb06daa6.png